# Python:: assign random values but should include specific number

Tags: python, arrays, random

I know how to create an array includes random values, but I would like to have at least one number equal to specific value, and all random values should be greater than 1 ?

```
import numpy as np
x=np.random.rand(1,4)
specif_value=3
print(x)
#x=[2 3 1 1]
```

Comment: Create an array with random values. Then pick one of the elements at random and replace it with your specific value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the docs for `numpy.random.rand` [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.rand.html). It appears you want an array of random non-zero integers, in which case you should be using `randint`(docs [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html))

This code will give you an output array with a specific value in the specified index

```
import numpy as np 

# Creating random array
size = 4
minimum_value = 1
maximum_value = 100
x = np.random.randint(minimum_value, maximum_value, size)

# Including specified value
specified_value = 3
specified_value_index = 2
x[specified_value_index] = specified_value

print(x)
```

Note that `randint` requires a maximum value if you want non-zero integers; otherwise it will return values between 0 and the given minimum